# Getting file path from file name located in a directory in java

Tags: java, file, jasper-reports

I have some jasper reports file inside a directory called "reports" which is located 2-3 level at the bottom of the "src" package in eclipse IDE. How could get the related file paths inside "reports" folder. I don't want to get the paths like "C:\Users\Kara\workspace\MyProject\src\main\resources\reports\someFile.jrxml". I tried to get them by following code but it didn't give me the real path.

```
File testFile = new File("someFile.jrxml");
String absPath = testFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 2):

If the reports are alway in your classpath (which they appear to be, assuming a standard Maven directory layout), use `Class.getResource()/ClassLoader.getResource()` to get a URL pointing to your report file. You can use this URL to extract the absolute path to your report file.

```
URL reportUrl = getClass().getResource("reports/someFile.jrxml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/reports/someFile.jrxml");
url.getPath();
```

Comment: I think it should be `"reports/someFile.jrxml"` instead of `"/reports/someFile.jrxml"`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where does the "getClass()" method point to? I tried this code from inside a Test.java class but it didn't work, got Null Pointer Exception.  URL url = Test.class.getResource("/reports/someFile.jrxml");

Comment: In my local computer getClass().getResource(file path) works fine and I am able to pass ".jrxml" file path and generate reports. However, when build the project and deploy it in remote server the specified file cannot be found. I encounter "java.io.FileNotFoundException". Thanks alot for the consideration.